# Populate rows based on calendar-like data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In Excel, I have a table of employees/dates in which employees are at the vertical axis and dates at the horizontal. The table has data about the employees' day offs and vacations shown as "+".

I need something that will populate the same name to multiple rows based on how many times the sequence of "+" starts and will return at each row the day-offs that are together, as shown:

[image]

Coloring is only for understanding purposes. All cells are with "No fill".
This needs to be done to a massive database of 3000 people.

Comment: Note - SO is not mean to be a code-writing service. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Nope. I'm really clueless on where to start.

Comment: I honestly suggest rethinking your approach if you can. This setup does not feel like the most efficient solution to your issue.

Comment: Formulas are not going to do it for you.  This will require vba.

Comment: "I honestly suggest rethinking your approach if you can. This setup does not feel like the most efficient solution to your issue." I can't because the "data before" is already in this shape and not even my work. I just need to convert them to date ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me preface this answer by saying that I, too, do not think is an efficient, let alone the *most* efficient, approach to this problem, and it certainly isn't straightforward. I should put it more strongly than that, though, lest there be confusion: This is NOT a good way to solve this problem! With that out of the way, I could not resist this challenge.

I will try to post enough details for you to replicate my Excel file.

In case it isn't obvious, this can be extended to however many rows you have in your original table of employees with the "+"'s. You would start by putting in the original table. Then, update the two range names shown below to pick up all of your employees and all of your data. Skip a row, paste in the row of '1' through '31', and then paste in the two main formulas (i.e., the ones that start in cells **A9** and **B9**) in the row below that, making sure to replace any references to rows 8 and 9 with the newly applicable start rows, then drag down to as many rows as you need to pick up the pluses through the last row of original data! Add conditional formatting afterwards on the whole range if you want to see the color scheme for B/M/E/N (beginning, middle, end, next) appear automatically (optional step). Then, make an identically-sized section below the B/M/E/N section to put in your "If 'M' then '+' else blank" formula.

Here is a screenshot of the grid from the example file I created:

[image]

You'll need to create the following named ranges:

[image]

Optionally, if you want to see the colors in the picture appear automatically, you can create the following conditional formatting:

[image]

(You might find it easier to put in the conditional formatting after putting in the formulas, but if you want to put it in beforehand, make sure you paste special formulas only in that section)

Now, with the named ranges in place, here is what to put in the worksheet grid:

**Step 1:** Hard-code the data up to row 8.

**Step 2:** Enter the following formula in cell **A9** and drag down to cell **A22**

```
=IF(B8=1,INDEX(rngEmps,1),IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(rngData,MATCH(A8,rngEmps,0)-1,,1,),"+")=COUNTIF(OFFSET($B$8:$AF8,MATCH(A8,$A$8:$A8,0)-1,,COUNTA($A$8:$A8)+COUNTBLANK($A$8:$A8)-(MATCH(A8,$A$8:$A8,0)-1),),"M"),INDEX(rngEmps,MATCH(A8,rngEmps,0)+1),A8))
```

**Step 3:** Enter the following formula in cell **B9** and drag right and down to cell **AF22**

```
=IF($A9=$A8,IF(OR(B8="B",B8="M"),"B",IF(B8="E",IF(A9="B","B","E"),IF(OR(A9="B",A9="M"),"M","N"))),IF(B$2=1,IF(INDEX(rngData,MATCH($A9,rngEmps,0),1)="+","M","B"),IF(INDEX(OFFSET(rngData,MATCH($A9,rngEmps,0)-1,,1),1,B$8)="+",IF(OR(A9="E",A9="N"),"N","M"),IF(A9="B","B","E"))))
```

Let me know if you get stuck on this anywhere, Ragnar. Also, I'm guessing you can recreate the bottom section with the "+"'s.

**UPDATE/EDIT:** There was previously a slight bug in the main (cell A9) formula that I posted last night (10/23/2019) in that it didn't correctly handle the first column being "+"; that should be fixed now. Also, in general, I have not taken the time to thoroughly optimize these formulas (e.g., minimize repeated work as much as possible, ensure the ideal order of arranging IF statements, etc.). This is meant to be more of a proof of concept. Please post a comment if you find a bug in my solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I didn't have the time to test the solution thoroughly but from what I've seen I have some trouble to make the formulas work for different starting cells. And to be sure I got this right by this "Step 1: Hard-code the data up to row 8.", you mean that the data are just values, without any formulas behind them.

Comment: To be specific about my approach to the problem, I need the outcome to be a list of names (with duplicate values for multiple day offs) with the starting and ending date beside the name. With my Excel knowledge, I can extract the dates from a row that only contains a single period of "+"s but not with multiple ones. If there's a better way to do it than the population of rows, like I described at the original post, please let me know.

Comment: To your first comment, yes, the starting data is presumed to be "hard-coded", which means values without any formulas. As for a different starting row, which is obviously a must, I recommend reading carefully through the paragraph in my answer which begins with "In case it isn't obvious, this can be extended to however many rows you have...". Actually, after you update the two named ranges to pick up your ~3000 rows, and on a second look, the task is a bit easier than I described it in that the two main formulas actually copy down correctly without modification.

Comment: Seeing as the conditional formatting step is completely optional (it just provides colors on B/M/E/N; it doesn't affect any formula results), here are some new instructions:

Comment: 1) Paste the provided formulas into cells A9 and B9, as instructed in my answer.
2) Let's say you have exactly 3,000 rows of data. It will start in row 3 and end in row 3,002. Since the formulas go 3 rows below the end of the data, paste cells A9:B9 into cells A3005:B3005.
3) Copy the row of 1-31 into cells B3004:AF3004
4) Paste your raw data into cells A3:AF3002 (and make sure the row of 1-31 is above that in row 2)5

Comment: 5) Update the two range names to cover the ranges A3:A3002 and B3:AF3002; Google how to do that if needed.
6) Copy down and across the formulas in cells A3005:B3005 as needed; this will be some number of rows fewer than 93,000.
7) Once those formulas cover the correct range of rows, skip one more row, paste that whole range in as values (just to have content) but put in two new formulas: For the column, the values are correct (or you can put in =Bx where x is the starting row of the formula section above it). For the data =IF(Bx="M","+",""). That should do it for you!

Comment: I got it to work for a small example like yours and it works like a charm. Can this work when there are duplicate names in column A?

Comment: Yes! I got to work for the whole project. Thank you SO much!

Comment: Glad it worked for yout! I'd much appreciate it if you would mark my answer as accepted. It will not work for duplicate names because the original data row to match would be ambiguous.